# React: Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay So i have multiple question, (more or less basic ones)

**First Question**: When I do something like

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    person: [
    {id: "name1n", name: "Rohit", age: 24},
    {id: "name2l", name: "Hariom", age: 23},
    {id: "name3g", name: "Vaibhav", age: 58}
  ],
  someOtherState: "Untouched state",
  showPerson: false
}


var apple = 10;
```

Before render, it throws an error saying failed to compiler `var apple` but if I do same thing inside render like `render( var apple = 10; );` it does not throw the error. Can someone please explain the reason for same?

**Second Question** Inside render, when I do something like this

```
  render() {
const style = {
  width: '150px',
  margin: 'auto',
  color: 'white',
  padding: '5px',
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  marginBottom: '10px'
};

var apple = 10;
console.log(apple) // -> This log
    let person = null;
    if (this.state.showPerson) {
      person= (
        <div>
          {
            this.state.person.map((el, index) => {
              return <Person
              key={el.id}
              click={this.deletePersonHandler.bind(index)}
              name={el.name}
              age={el.age}
              changed={(event) => this.eventSwitchHandler(event, el.id)} />
            })
          }
       </div>
     );
    style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    apple = 20;
    console.log(apple) // -> This log
    }
  return (
  <div className="App">
        <h1> Hi I am react App</h1>
        <button style={style}
        onClick={this.togglerPersonHandler}>Button</button>
        {person}
    </div>
     )
   }
}
```

it logs `10` twice in console before displaying `20`, The question being why is it displaying the **`number 10 twice`** before displaying 20? Shouldn't it just console.log -> 10 and then 20? instead of 10 -> 10 -> 20?

**Third Question** when I click on button it changes the **BackgroundColor to red** and when I again click it, it reverts back to green colo
This is my **togglePersonHandler** which changes the state (showPerson) of If condition when button is clicked

```
togglerPersonHandler = () => {
  const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
  this.setState({
    showPerson: !doesShow
  });
}
```

**My third question is**, Why does it changed by itself to its original color (green) when I click it back again? I usually used to do it with else condition

Comment: Did you write that code by yourself? These are very basic questions. I suggest you make yourself familiar with javascript, es6 features and react by own research or doing one of the numerous react tutorials out there. Stackoverflow is intended to provide answers to **single** concrete programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a better practise to ask a single question in a single thread (helps other people having the same problem to read and navigate)

**First Question Answer**

You are declaring a variable inside a class, which is not permitted though You can do something like this inside a class

```
apple = 10
```

and then make a method

```
    printMyname = () => {
    console.log(this.apple)
}
```

And then call it **outside the class** by doing something like this

```
const app1 = new App ()
app1.printMyname()
```

Inside the method you can declare `var apple = 10` (or you can declare it globally) and call it inside the **method**

**Second Question and third question**

This happens because the state of the event most likely changed when it rendered.

So here is how it actually worked.

when it first rendered the page it logged **10**. 
Initially your state is false so **it won't print 20** 
When the state changed it console.logged **10 again and then 20**
the next time the state changes, it will again **console log 10 and 20**

so you log should appear like **10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10....**

Similarly for background change

**state.changed (false)** -> it re-renders initial style hence it shows green.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example fails to compile because your can't declare variables in a `class` scope. You can only declare properties of that class:

```
class Foo {
    aProperty = "Foo";

    static aStaticProperty = 42;

    aFunction() {
         console.log("I am a function");
    }

    static aStaticFunction() {
        console.log("I am a static function");
    }   
}
```

`render()` is just a function that has to be declared in every react component class.

Your second example may show that behaviour because a component does call its `render()` function every time the state or props change. So on the first render `this.state.showPerson` might be `false` so that your second `console.log()` will not be called (because it's in the conditional block). The second time it gets called `this.state.showPerson` have changed to `true` thus both `console.log()`s are executed.